# $ adb shell am start -n "" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet

Tags: android, android-studio

So, i just  **updated my Android Studio from 1.5.1 to 2.1 Preview 1 thru canary channel** . Now when i was trying to run my app on my device then i had to face these errors.

`03/16 18:40:12: Launching app
$ adb push D:\Workspace\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.shienh.myapplication
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.shienh.myapplication"
Segmentation fault`

$ adb shell am start -n "com.shienh.myapplication/com.shienh.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..

What could be the reason for such an error.
And yes, app was not installed on device.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's not working, it's not depends on Android Studio version. Maybe did you make any mispelling? Make sure that grammar of this command is correct.

For pushing app on device, unistalling it or clearing user data consider to use this IntelliJ/Android Studio plugin:
https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea

It gives you direct  access to pimary `adb` commands, like in an image below:

[image]

Just in your IDE choose `File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install from repository`(second option)

Search for ADB IDEA and install the plugin.

Hope it help

Comment: i have done as you said but, the problem was solved after i restarted my AS and unplugged and re-plugged my device. I think AS or adb was taking time to adjust itself. Anyway thanks for answer.